# Virus forces system re-install. Can I save essential documents to transfer to clean operating system?

Tags: backup, virus

As the title indicates, I have some virus issues and have read on this site that the best course of action is to re-install my OS.

I am an unsophisticated user and, as a result, have no backup of my important files in place but want to save essential documents (word/excel/notepad) before I wipe everything out.  Can I do this (and if so, how) without, so to speak, bringing the viruses with me when I start running these documents after the re-install?

Also, since I have lost any discs associated with my computer purchase, is there still a way that is built into the computer to accomplish what it is I am trying to do?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

The solution which I think will best help you is to use a boot CD to gain access to your old files, copy your files from the old drive to a flashdrive/external drive, and then reinstall your system.

Here is a guide on how to recover your files using a bootcd and links to Knoppix (a specific boot cd): http://lifehacker.com/192982/geek-to-live--rescue-files-with-a-boot-cd

There are 2 options in terms of loading a new Operating System:
1) Most laptops and many pre-build computers come with what is called a 'recovery partition' this is essentially a 'disk' that is put on your PC which contains your operating system installers. To access this, on boot go in to the 'bios' and see if there are any options listed under Boot Options->hard disk (you can probably search for your exact model on Google to find out what the specific wording will be). After you are at the boot options menu, see if there are multiple options under 'Hard Disk' (again, may not be exact term) If so, try booting to the other one and see if that brings you to an operating system installer.

2) If you do not have a recovery partition you will need to determine what operating system you want/need (not sure if you have your activation key, it may need to be repurchased if you no longer have it)

If you use windows 7, go to: http://www.techverse.net/download-windows-7-iso-x86-x64-microsofts-official-servers/ to get an 'ISO' downloaded. You can then use this tool to mount it properly on a USB Drive: http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool

From there, follow this guide to boot to usb and reinstall your system: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/a/install-windows-7-usb.htm

(If you are using a Mac please add additional info in your description and I'm sure someone else can help with your issues)

Hope this helps!